# How to format number inputs in rails form_for as the user types

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, forms, form-for

How to format float type numbers in form inputs as the user types?

There seems to be a couple jquery plugins...but none that are great.  HTML5 is somewhat helpful...but, limited in its ability.  Just wondering if there is a super easy way to do this that I am overlooking...

In form_for f.text_field if a user types ".1" it should be immediately changed to "0.1".  If the user types "1"...it should be changed to "1.0", etc.

I am storing numbers as strings because Im using postgres hstore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 type="number" was no help in this situation.  None of the jQuery plugins I found were helpful.  But, it was super simple (not sure why I ever looked further than my own code) to implement.

```
jQuery ->
$("input.sum_number").change ->
  str = $(this).val()
  if str.charAt(0) == "."
    $(this).val("0#{str}")
  if str.charAt(str.length - 2) != "."
    $(this).val("#{str}.0")
```